# Check if an object (not an element) really exists with js/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this string of code, data is value returned inside a success callback in an ajax environment:

```
$('#cpt_rspp_value').text(data.Payload.Clerks.rspp.full_name)
$('#cpt_ddl_value').text(data.Payload.Clerks.ddl.full_name)
$('#cpt_rls_value').text(data.Payload.Clerks.rls.full_name)
$('#cpt_mc_value').text(data.Payload.Cler.mc.full_name)
$('#cpt_se_value').text(data.Payload.Clerks.se.full_name)
```

If, `rspp` really exists inside the DB the object `data.Payload.Clerks.rspp.full_name` will be  present, so I can put it in right place (i.e: `#cpt_rspp_value`).
But, alas, if that object doesn't exist, the js interpreter will stop, and so, even if next objects `data.Payload.Clerks.ddl.full_name`, `data.Payload.Clerks.rls.full_name` and so on, will be present, that row will never been processed.

I should "if" any lines, but how? `if(data.Payload.Clerks.rspp.full_name)` and `if(data.Payload.Clerks.rspp.full_name != null)` don't resolve the issue. 
What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**typeof**](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/typeof.php) javascript operator to check if the object defined,

```
if(typeof data.Payload.Clerks.rspp.full_name != 'undefined')
```

or

```
if(typeof data.Payload.Clerks.rspp != 'undefined')
```

Comment: In my case, the right code is `if(typeof data.Payload.Clerks.rspp != 'undefined')` without `full_name`, cause `rspp` is missing too.

Answer (score 3):

For checking if it's strictly an `object`

```
if(typeof myobject === 'object')
```

In your case, check for `string` type

```
if( typeof data.Payload.Clerks.rspp.full_name === 'string')
```

Personal opinion - you could just use `if(rspp.full_name)` since it's a trivial check in the larger scheme of things. (from what it seems like in the question)  :)